# 3ds max material shows in render but not vrml export

Tags: render, raytracing, 3dsmax, vrml

I created a model of a bottle in 3ds max, and used a raytrace material (in Materials -> Standard -> Raytrace, not the raytrace map). Everything looks great in the 3ds max render, but when exported to vrml, all that shows up is the default blue colour as if it had no material assigned to it!
I have exported to vrml using "standard" materials with no problems, so is this material type unsupported in vrml or is there actually a way to get it to show up?
Thanks

edit: I'm in 3ds max 2013, in case that's relevant at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unsupported. Usually exporters only handles certain materials during export (typically "standard" materials with bitmap textures).
Also raytrace material is not a material usually used in realtime applications, so there is no reason for them to support it.

Also rendering output and export output is two totally different things, so you cannot compare them, since the render output is made by the render engine you use, and the export output is dependent on both the format and the software used to display the output geometry.